# How to return -1 if no numerical values have been inserted?

Tags: javascript

I have an issue. I would like to ignore the string and log the second highest number regardless of the number of strings. I would also like to return -1 if no numerical values have been inserted.
Can anybody help?

```js
secondHighestDigit = function(input) {

  var nums = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    nums.push(parseInt(input[i]));
  }
  nums.sort();

  return nums[nums.length - 2];
};

console.log(secondHighestDigit("4324"));
console.log(secondHighestDigit("ab341"));
```

First console log works, the second one outputs NaN. I tried making a isNan statement but it did not work properly.

Comment: `I tried making a isNan statement`  where? show the code, you'll learn from your mistakes

Comment: Sure, I tried something like this   if (isNaN(nums)){
      console.log(-1)
    }

Comment: From the documentation on parseInt:  `If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point.`

Comment: You can use the charAt method to individually check each character of input is number or alphabet. Add all numbers in stack and sort

Comment: Yes, so I have used parseInt with the expectation that all non numerical values will be ignored, but whenever i insert more than one non numerical value it returns NaN

Comment: @JFurgalski If its non-numeric then why are you pushing it in the array ? Thats simple dont push if its NaN

Comment: @Yo Yo omg, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. I was so close! But I went off tracks and started writing lines of if statements that were over-complicating the code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
secondHighestDigit = function(input) {

  var nums = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(input[i])) nums.push(-1); // check input[i] is number
    else nums.push(parseInt(input[i]));
  }
  nums.sort();

  return nums[nums.length - 2];
};

console.log(secondHighestDigit("4324"));
console.log(secondHighestDigit("ab341"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to test if there are any numbers in the provided string.

```js
secondHighestDigit = function(input) {

  if (/\d/.test(input)) {
    var nums = [];
    
    input.split("").forEach(num => {
      if(!isNaN(num)) nums.push(parseInt(num));
    });

    return nums.sort((a, b) => b - a)[1];
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
};

console.log(secondHighestDigit("4324"));
console.log(secondHighestDigit("ab341"));
console.log(secondHighestDigit("abaa"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue with your check of doing:

```
if (isNaN(nums)){ console.log(-1) }
```

Is the fact that `nums` is always an array. It is not the thing which evaluates to `NaN`. The thing which evaluates to `NaN` is an element (ie character) when you use `parseInt(input[i])`. Thus, you need to check if the *element* you are returning is `NaN`, not the `nums` array.

See example below:

```js
secondHighestDigit = function(input) {

  var nums = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    nums.push(parseInt(input[i]));
  }
  nums.sort();
  
  var result = nums[nums.length - 2]; // store desired result
  if(!isNaN(result)) { // if the result IS a number (ie: not not a number)
    return result; // return the result stored away
  }
  return -1; // if we get to this part of the code, we know our number is NaN and so we can return -1
};

console.log(secondHighestDigit("4324")); // 4
console.log(secondHighestDigit("ab341")); // -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it like this

```js
secondHighestDigit = function(input) {
  const a = input
    .split('')
    .filter(e => !isNaN(e))
    .sort()
    .filter((a,b,c) => c.indexOf(a) === b)
  return a.length >= 2 ? parseInt(a.slice(-2)[0]) : -1;
};

console.log("01010101", secondHighestDigit("01010101"));
console.log("1111", secondHighestDigit("1111"));
console.log("aaaaa", secondHighestDigit("aaaaa"));
console.log("4324", secondHighestDigit("4324"));
console.log("ab341", secondHighestDigit("ab341"));
console.log("1234561234123hasdjk", secondHighestDigit("1234561234123hasdjk"));
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `||` operator to add a -1 to the array in case `parseInt()` returns `NaN`? Check the code below:

```js
secondHighestDigit = function(input) {

  var nums = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    nums.push(parseInt(input[i]) || -1); // -1 if the int can't be parsed
  }
  nums.sort();

  return nums[nums.length - 2];
};

console.log(secondHighestDigit("4324"));
console.log(secondHighestDigit("ab341"));
console.log(secondHighestDigit("aaa")); // Array with no numbers, just to check if it returns -1
```

If you want to treat the case where the string is smaller than 2 characters, you can use the `||` operator to return -1 as well, replacing your return with:

```
return nums[nums.length - 2] || -1; // -1 if the array is smaller than 2
```